# Starcraft 2 Building Previews

Tags: starcraft-2

After watching Idra's stream, I noticed something. When he builds a building, after picking the spot where to build, there is a preview placed on the ground and for him it is a bright pink.

[image: Idras Buildings]

However, when I build something, my preview is a faded out version of the building and not at all clear to see.

[image: My Buildings]

I'm looking for how to change my settings to be the same as his. My current graphics settings are low graphics with Ultra textures and I've tried with low-low and ultra-ultra but I can't seem to get the pink previews.

Any help?

BTW .. It may not seem like a big deal and it rarely is, but I have my hotkeys set so that the spore and spine crawler buttons are next to each other so sometimes I build a wall of spores instead of spines which isn't great vs ground based compositions as you can imagine.

Comment: My guess is that it's a result of texture quality, or some other obtuse setting.

Comment: Definitely a graphics option. Dunno which one off the top of my head, though.

Comment: there is a tool tip for each graphics option, I suggest reading them

Comment: This seems like a graphical setting to me too. I havent even noticed what my own previews looks like. Id say trial and error regarding this. Play agains an easy AI. and try in-game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this when switching my graphics from medium to low. All my previews went from pinkish to gray when I did so. When I switched them back after the game, which was really laggy, the previews switched back to pink.